# using a class's instance in other class?

Tags: java, println, system.out

When we the statement `System.out.println()` in java to output something on screen.
In this statement `System` is the class, `out` is the object of that class, `println()` is the method of that class.

When we declare an instance or object of, suppose, class A in class B, then following syntax is used, `A object;`, and then if there are any methods of the class, which have been declared as public, then in following syntax the methods are called, `object.method(argument)`.

Now my question is that why we can't declare the object, `out`, of the class, `System`, in the following syntax, `System out = new System();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this statement "System" is the class, "out" is the object of that class,

No, [`out` is a static **field** within `System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out). It's a field which returns a reference to a `PrintStream`. It's *not* an instance of `System`. So you can use:

```
PrintStream stream = System.out;
stream.println("Foo");
```

(It's important to distinguish between classes, objects, fields, references etc by the way. Taking some time to get the terminology right can really help you understand it correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

[`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) has a private constructor that you cannot access:

```
64    private System() {
65    }
```

([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java))

If by `System out = new System()` you're trying to reassign `System.out`... well you can't do that either, since [`out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is `final` and hence cannot be reassigned after it has been initialized (not to mention it's of type `PrintWriter`, and not `System`).

Comment: `out` is most definitely not `final`, and reassigning it to redirect standard output is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think so: [`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).

Comment: Odd; the `final` keyword doesn't appear in the main Javadoc, and it looks to be a bug in the specification (the behavior of the field, which was inherited since 1.0, doesn't match the new `final` semantics in the JLS for Java 5). You can't directly assign to the field (for security reasons), but you can call `setOut`.

Comment: @chrylis `out` has been `final` from Java 1.

Comment: You appear to be right, but it can also be changed. I don't think this behavior technically violated the original JLS, but I believe it does violate the current one. The JLS requirement isn't enforced here because `System` necessarily has to be implemented natively in the JVM.

Comment: @chrylis Can you provide a quote / passage from the JLS that you believe is violated?

Comment: "Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

Comment: @chrylis That is in no way violated here.

Comment: Why not? If I call `System#setOut`, the `final` field `System.out` will then refer to a different object.

Comment: Actually, I had not seen clause 17.5.4. The three specific fields `System.{in,out,err}` are special-cased in the spec and have to be special-cased in the compiler because of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how the Java syntax works. In `System.out`, [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a class. The dot operator means that `out` is a *member* of that class (in this case a variable, not a method, because there are no parentheses), not an instance of it. `out` is an object of type `PrintStream`, and you could in fact create new instances of `PrintStream`s (such as by opening files for writing).

`System` happens to be a special Java class that you can't instantiate yourself. For most classes, you can use the syntax you described:
    Car myCar = new Car();

Answer (score 0):

**out** – is a `static member field` of [**System**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class and is of type  [**PrintStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Its access specifiers are `public final`.

This gets instantiated during startup and gets mapped with standard output console of the host.

[See how it works](http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/)